# Elasticsearch DSL with multiple multi_match query in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I have this scenario wherein there are two multi_match searches within the same query. The trouble is, when I create the JSON for it in ruby, a json with non-unique keys doesn't seem possible so only one of them appear.

Here is my query:

```
{
    "fields": ["id", "title", 
    "address.city", "address.state", "address.country", "address.state_code", "address.country_code", "proxy_titles", "location"],
    "size":2,
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "custom_score": {
                        "gte": 100
                    }
                }
            },
            "query":{
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "multi_match":{
                            "query": "term 1",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "fields": ["title^2", "proxy_titles^2","description"]
                        }
                    },
                    "must": {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "us",
                            "fields": ["address.city", "address.country", "address.state",
                            "address.zone", "address.country_code", "address.state_code", "address.zone_code"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "_score": { "order": "desc" },
        "variation": {"order": "asc"},
        "updated_at": { "order": "desc" }
    }
}
```

I have also only recently started using elasticsearch so it be very helpful if you could suggest me a better query to accomplish the same as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the syntax wrong. For multiple `"must"` values in a `"bool"`, they need to be in an array. The documentation is not always terribly helpful, unfortunately (the [bool query page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) shows this for `"should"` but not `"must"`).

Try this:

```
{
   "fields": ["id","title","address.city","address.state","address.country","address.state_code","address.country_code","proxy_titles","location"],
   "size": 2,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "range": {
               "custom_score": {
                  "gte": 100
               }
            }
         },
         "query": {
            "bool": [
               {
                  "must": {
                     "multi_match": {
                        "query": "term 1",
                        "type": "cross_fields",
                        "fields": ["title^2","proxy_titles^2","description"]
                     }
                  }
               },
               {
                  "must": {
                     "multi_match": {
                        "query": "us",
                        "fields": ["address.city","address.country","address.state","address.zone","address.country_code","address.state_code","address.zone_code"]
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "sort": {
      "_score": {
         "order": "desc"
      },
      "variation": {
         "order": "asc"
      },
      "updated_at": {
         "order": "desc"
      }
   }
}
```